# Error when running launch file Marker.launch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I study book Programming Robots with ROS Morgan Quigley, Brian Gerkey & William D. Smart
I try launch file in chapter14 stuckroom_bot markers.launch
in this chapter14 robot is fetchbot, ros version is indigo

markers.launch

-when launch this file, then appear this err message

... logging to /home/ho/.ros/log/da9b7b56-1299-11e7-83ee-000c29c6431a/roslaunch-ubuntu-51819.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: mismatched tag: line 38, column 2
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

--

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257938/error-when-running-launch-file-marker.launch/) by [deokisys](https://answers.ros.org/users/29833/deokisys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tags for the `tag_rot` and `tag_trans` don't have a `/` at the end: `... default="0 -0.28 -0.1 0 0 0" />`

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) with karma: 366 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1